# ssh connection dropped with Python

Tags: python, ssh, ssh-tunnel, pexpect

I usually establish ssh tunnel this way:

```
ssh -ND 6666 -vvv -p 443 user@server
```

server's answer:

```
[...]
user@server's password: 
....
debug1: pledge: network
```

From there I know the tunnel is established.if not in vvv mode I check the tunnel status with netstat.

```
netstat -tl
```

Here is my corresponding python3 script:

```
import pexpect, sys

def ssh_con(host,user,password):
   child = pexpect.spawn("ssh -ND 6666 -vvv -p 443 %s@%s" % (user,host))
   i = child.expect([pexpect.TIMEOUT, 'password: '])
   if i == 0: #timeoutx
      print( "ssh connection timeout")
      sys.exit(1)
   if i == 1:
      print("ssh connection ok, sending password...")
      child.sendline(password)
      i = child.expect([pexpect.TIMEOUT, 'pledge: network'])
      if i==0:
         print("password timeout issue")
         sys.exit(1)
   elif i==1:
        print("tunnel sould be up and running now")

def main():       
  host = '206.189.126.158'
  user = 'cloudssh.us-jvkgouyg'
  password = 'lijuhih'

  child = ssh_con( host, user, password)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

I have got 2 main problems:

1. as soon as the tunnel comes up ("tunnel sould be up and running now"), bash prompt comes back and the connection is lost immediately. (netstat shows FIN_WAIT)
2. Another strange thing is that I have got a password timeout (from time to time). I am just wondering wether it would a good idea to introduce a delay at the password prompt.

Thankx folks!

Comment: try `ssh -f`. it'll run in background. otherwise it'll be killed when pexpect exits.

Comment: ssh -f does not help at all. I can perfectly automatize the tunnel establishment under bash with expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it! readbuffer size is set to default. So I needed to remove the ultra verbose mode from the ssh command (-vvv), and all pexpect commands related to the verbose output. I also needed to set the timeout to None for infinite, or to 300 for 5 min ...